# Strange result of 2D cross-correlation using OpenCV's matchTemplate method in Python

Tags: python, matlab, opencv, scipy, octave

In the following example the cross-correlation of the A,B arrays is calculated using the cv2.matchTemplate method. The result is stored in the C array:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
A=np.ones((3,3), dtype=np.uint8)
B=np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]], dtype=np.uint8)
C=cv2.matchTemplate( A, B, cv2.TM_CCORR )

>>> A
    array([[1, 1, 1],
           [1, 1, 1],
           [1, 1, 1]], dtype=uint8)
>>> B
    array([[1, 2, 3],
           [4, 5, 6],
           [7, 8, 9]], dtype=uint8)
>>> C
    array([[ 45.]], dtype=float32)
```

Let's implement the same example using **scipy**:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import scipy
import scipy.signal

A = np.ones((3,3), dtype=np.uint8)
B = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]], dtype=np.uint8)
C = scipy.signal.correlate2d(A,B)

>>> C
array([[ 9, 17, 24, 15,  7],
       [15, 28, 39, 24, 11],
       [18, 33, 45, 27, 12],
       [ 9, 16, 21, 12,  5],
       [ 3,  5,  6,  3,  1]], dtype=uint8)
```

Let's now implement the same example using **Octave**:

```
octave:4> A=ones(3,3)
A =

   1   1   1
   1   1   1
   1   1   1

octave:5> B=[1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9]
B =

   1   2   3
   4   5   6
   7   8   9

octave:6> C=xco
xcorr   xcorr2  xcov    
octave:6> C=xcorr2(A,B)
C =
    9   17   24   15    7
   15   28   39   24   11
   18   33   45   27   12
    9   16   21   12    5
    3    5    6    3    1
```

By comparing the results we can see that the opencv's method generates significantly different result.

Could someone explain the difference between the various implementations of the 2D cross-correlation?

What should I change to my opencv code in order to compute the 2D cross-correlation properly?

Thank you all,

funk

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, to begin we need to refer to the OpenCV documentation:

#### Matlab/OpenCV

```
cv2.matchTemplate(image, templ, method[, result]) → result
```

- `result` – Map of comparison results. It must be single-channel 32-bit floating-point. If image is  `W x H` and `templ` is  `w x h` , then result is `(W-w+1) x (H-h+1)`.

With a 3x3 image and a 3x3 template, your result will be a `(3-3+1)x(3-3+1) = (1x1)` matrix, which is what the method actually did return.

The formula used by the `TM_CCORR` method is as follows:

[image: OpenCV implementation]

Now let's look at the difference between this and the other implementations.

#### SciPy

```
scipy.signal.correlate2d(in1, in2, mode='full', boundary='fill', fillvalue=0)[source]
```

The result size is determined by the `mode` parameter. Using the default parameter of `full` means that the result size will be `(W+w-1) x (H+h-1)`. However, changing the mode to `valid` will result in a `(W-w+1) x (H-h+1)` result, which is the same as that achieved by OpenCV.

#### Octave

```
C = xcorr2(A,B)
```

The size of the result matrix is:

- `C_rows = A_rows + B_rows - 1`
- `C_cols = A_cols + B_cols - 1`

With a 3x3 image and a 3x3 template, your result will be a `(3+3-1)x(3+3-1)=(5x5)` matrix.

The formula used by this method appears different than that used by OpenCV, but is actually just a different form of the same equation.

[image: Octave]

## Conclusions

The formulas used in all three implementations appear to be the same. The reason for the difference between the methods is the way that boundary conditions are handled. Cross-correlation is achieved by "sliding" the template matrix over the image matrix and setting the result sum for a given cell to the sum of the products of the overlapping cells in the image and template. However, for the edge cases in the image, unless the template is a 1x1 matrix, it will overlap the edge of the image (see the picture below for an example). This case can be handled by padding or wrapping the image. In the first case, the image is enlarged and padded with zeros to ensure that the template cannot overhang the image.

[image: Overlap]

In both SciPy and Octave, the default method is to pad the image, which will generate an image that is larger than the input image (indeed, in the case of two 3x3 matrices, the result is 5x5 because the template overhangs the image by a total of 2 rows and 2 columns when centered on the edge cells of the image). In OpenCV, the default method is to drop the edge cases where the template hangs over the image, which in this instance means that the only valid position for the template is centered exactly over the center of the image. This explains the single result cell with a value of 45: the sum of all elements of the template multiplied times 1.

To answer your question of how to get the same results using the Matlab implementation of OpenCV: simply enlarge the input matrix so that the size is 
`(W+w-1) x (H+h-1)`, center the image in the new matrix and pad the area outside of the image with 0's:

```
A=padarray(np.ones((3,3), dtype=np.uint8), [1, 1])
```

Comment: Great answer! Thank you very much!